# How i can add some data as text to text file which had data already

Tags: c#, winforms, text

I want to add some data to text file when i code with winform by C#. But when i check file, it has only textboxno2 text. I know my code was wrong. How i can do it? plz help me.
Thank for your support!

```
//check file exsists
string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Text.txt";
if (!File.Exists("Text.txt"))
   File.Create("Text.txt").Close();

//insert text form textbox no1
using (StreamWriter text1 = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
      text1.WriteLine(txtNo1.Text);
      text1.Close();
}

//insert text form textbox no2
using (StreamWriter text2 = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
      text1.WriteLine(txtNo2.Text);
      text1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your second using block references using text2 but you reference text1 within that block.

Comment: You can also use [File.AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext) (or `File.AppendText`). No need to check whether the file exists or (try to) create it. Is that `text1` a typo (you should see it underlined in red)? Note that you're checking for the existence (`File.Exists("Text.txt")`) and use a File Path (`string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Text.txt";`) which, potentially, do not represent the same path (you should use `File.Exists(filePath)` - unless it's another *typo*). Use `Path.Combine()` to build Paths.

Comment: [StreamWriter constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) has overload with `append` parameter. Set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way if you don't know much is to read all text from the text file and write it back again with the new text.

```
string oldtext = File.ReadAllText("yourfilepath");
File.WriteAllText("yourfilepath", String.Empty);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("yourfilepath")
{
   writer.Write(oldtext);
   writer.Write("new text");
}
```

OR even better use AppendAllText

```
File.AppendAllText(@"yourfilepath", "new text");
```

Change your existing code as below and it will work(Sorry @Nathan!):

```
string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Text.txt";
if (!File.Exists("Text.txt"))
   File.Create("Text.txt").Close();

//insert text form textbox no1
using (StreamWriter text1 = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
      text1.WriteLine(txtNo1.Text);
      text1.Close();
}

//insert text form textbox no2
using (StreamWriter text2 = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
      text2.WriteLine(txtNo2.Text);//Changes here
      text2.Close();//Changes here
}
```

Comment: I used this and success. Thanks you so much File.AppendAllText(@"yourfilepath", "new text");